# Navigate to a division of a external html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am developing a cordova mobile application on netbeans and I have multiple html pages. In some html pages, there are page divisions like described [here.](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/pages/)
I have a login division on my page and fields must be filled for proceeding. I am using java script validating for that. hare is my code for that.

```
     <form id="frm_login">
                    <div class="ui-field-contain">
                        <input type="text" name="txt_username" id="txt_username" placeholder="username" value="" class="required">
                        <input type="password" data-clear-btn="true" name="password" placeholder="password" id="txt_password" value="" autocomplete="off" class="required">
                    </div>
                    <a href="" id="btn_login" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" onclick="login()">Login</a>
                    <a href="signup.html"  class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">SignUp</a>
     </form>
```

After validating I need to go to the page division required. Here is my js file for that.I have just one html page called index.html.

```
function login() {
    var val = $("#frm_login").valid()

    if (val) {
        window.location.reload(true);
        window.location.href = 'index.html#homepage';
  }

}
```

but this does not work. How to solve this.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)#Syntax" target="_blank">Java</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w2Z93/

Comment: it does not work on cordova. It just redirect to the same page where I am

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is a long shot :)

Change this code to

```
if (val) {
    localStorage.setItem("page_location","homepage");
    document.location="index.html";
}
```

In the `index.html`, inside device ready function or in any page load function

```
 check=localStorage.getItem("page_location");
 if(check=="homepage")
      jQuery.mobile.changePage("#homepage");
```

This should bring the GOAL for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. What I had to do was just remove the code line

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

now my js file is this

```
function login() {
    var val = $("#frm_login").valid()

    if (val) {
        window.location.href = 'index.html#homepage';
  }

}
```